# ADO Release IIS Web App Manage Task Physical Path as an expression

Tags: iis, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

How do I specify the physical path as an expression with a variable like `release-n` when managing a virtual application in an ADO IIS Web App Manage task?

We're just getting started with ADO Releases to IIS servers. We have IIS Web App Manage and Deployment tasks working, but only to a static physical path on the server.

I would like to store the new releases in versioned directories, and have the virtual application updated to point to the version being deployed.

For example

```
  Default Web Site
       /card-poc     <-- web application stored outside of wwwroot
           /release-1
           /release-2
           ...
           /release-n   <-- IIS virtual application physical path is pointed to here
```

So in an ADO Release IIS Web App Manage task, how do I specify the physical path as an expression with a variable like `release-n`?

I've tried `d:\IIS_VDs\CARD-poc\Release-$(rev:r)\` to get the release name, but I get the error

`The given path's format is not supported.`

The expected outcome is that the directory would be created, the virtual application would be altered to point to the new directory, and then the subsequent IIS Web App Deploy task would copy the files to the new dir. The goal is to allow a server operator to roll back an application to a prior version without knowledge of or access to to ADO, Version Control, or really anything except the IIS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested `$(rev:r)` and got the same error as you. I think the problem is getting the value of the `$(rev:r)` variable. I try to `Write-Host "$(rev:r)"` in the powershell task, but the task cannot get the value of `$(rev:r)`.  According to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55061357/11508192) , it seems `$(rev:r)` is a special variable format that **only works** in the Number field in the editor.

[image]

As workaround, you can try to use `Release.ReleaseName` predefined variable.

[Release.ReleaseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) : The name of the current release. Example: `Release-47`

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are right! I got `$(rev:r)` from the default release name pattern in the release options, so I would have expected it to work correctly, but Release.ReleaseName or ReleaseID work correctly! Many Thanks!